# Java: The fatorial doesn't give the right result, but I didn't find errors.

Tags: java, bluej

I developed my codes for fatorial in Java, compiling and running in a terminal with BlueJ. I corrected the error, but the fatorial doesn't give the right result. Check the code:

```
public class Fatorial
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        int i, fat = 4;

        for (i=1;i<fat;i++)
        {
            fat=fat*i;
        }
        System.out.print(fat);
    }
}
```

The right reuslt should be `fator(4) = 24`.

It should be similar to like:

```
public class Fatorial3 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int num, fatorial, aux; 

        num = 4; 
        aux = num; 

        fatorial = 1; 

        while(aux > 1){ 
            fatorial = fatorial * (aux);// Aqui não podemos subtrair 1, porque assim seria o fatorial de num-1 (4). 
            aux--; 
        } 
        System.out.println("O fatorial de "+num+" é: "+fatorial); 
    } 
}
```

But I want to keep my original codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you unroll the loop structure, this is what you are doing:

```
int i, fat = 4; // fat is 4 
i = 1;          // i is 1
fat = fat * i;  // fat = 4 * 1 = 4 
++i;            // i is 2
fat = fat * i;  // fat = 4 * 2 = 8
++i;            // i is 3
fat = fat * i;  // fat = 8 * 3 = 24
++i;            // i is 4, and that is less than 24, so keep going...
```

Eventually, `fat` overflows, and becomes negative, so the loop will terminate, and `fat` will be a large negative number.

If you want to keep a similar structure, add another variable to represent the argument of the factorial operator:

```
int i, n = 4, fat = 1;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  fat=fat*i;
}
System.out.print(fat);
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive solution would be to iterate down instead of up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(factorial(4));
}

public static long factorial(long num) {
    for (long i = num-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        num=num*i;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Like in the `Fatorial3` solution included in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a do...while loop. :)

```
public static int factorial(int number){
    int result= 1;
    int currentNumber = number;
    do{
    result = result * currentNumber;
    currentNumber--;
    }while (currentNumber > 1);

    return result;
}
```

Then you would just print the returned result...

```
System.out.println(factorial(4));
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean factorial? You can do it this way and it's far more easier using recursion

```
public class Factorial {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(fact(4));
}

public static long fact (long n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n * fact (n-1);
}
```

}

By the way when you're using for loop, you don't have to declare "i" outside the loop. Declaration is in the loop `for (int i = 0; i < fat; i++)`

Comment: This guy appears to be a novice programmer: I wouldn't suggest recursion as the idea for this would be to improve his understanding.

Answer (score -1):

You're reassigning i to be 4 when you declare your for loop. The reason the stated answer uses three variables for the loop is so that we don't multiply by 0 or any negative number.

Another suggestion for me would be to never declare multiple variables on the same line: It makes ones code hard to read and understand at a glance. In this case, both i and fat are being assigned 4 but this is not immediately obvious.

Another problem is that you are checking against fat, which changes with every execution of the loop. You need to be checking against a number which does not change, but fat does.

Try splitting up your variable declaration and reposting what you intend on working, that may help us guide you to where you want to be.